# Human-readable XML output from Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

Scala seems to do two things to XML that you enter that make it no less parseable but make it less readable:

First, it expands tags that close themselves:

```
scala> <tag/>
res109: scala.xml.Elem = <tag></tag>
```

And second, it scrambles attributes into random order, as if it put them into a hash set:

```
scala> <tag a="a" b="b" c="c" d="d"/>         
res110: scala.xml.Elem = <tag d="d" a="a" c="c" b="b"></tag>
```

Together, these conspire to render XML considerably less human-readable (at least by me).  I'm not very familiar with the XML library; is there a way to perform xml-to-string translation that yields a compact human-readable form?  (If not by default, by recursing and writing one's own string conversions--or are there too many special cases that lurk there?)

Comment: "Human-readable XML" -- made my day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly, see `scala.xml.Utility.toXml`. The attribute thing doesn't have a solution, though (as far as I know).

```
scala> xml.Utility.toXML(<a/>, minimizeTags = true)
res13: StringBuilder = <a />
```

You may want to look at `scala.xml.PrettyPrinter` as well.

Comment: It's a pity about the attributes.  That's the bigger problem with what I'm trying to do.  Maybe I'll just decide that no-one should read XML.

Comment: @Rex Anti-XML FTW. I think this is one of the points that bugged Spiewak. Well, actually, everything about attributes in scala.xml.

Comment: Indeed. I already have PML'ed in a bunch of operators to make working with attributes halfway manageable.